# Flex AsyncToken for listening to Alert box buttons

Tags: apache-flex, asynctoken

Can I listen to Alert button click between components using AsyncToken?
Basically, I want to have a method that opens an Alert with buttons and have it return an AsyncToken so that other components calling that method can listen for button click.

Example:

```
var token:AsyncToken=methodThatOpensAlert();
token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(buttonClick));
```

What's the way to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use an AsyncToken to achieve this but you could also just register for custom events that you dispatch from the pop up, this is a much cleaner method IMO.  Really you've got two relatively clean options I can think of.  1 you make your pop-up dispatch events like "okClicked" "cancelClicked" for different button clicks within the pop-up, you create an instance of the pop up and add listeners then call PopUpManager.addPopUp, or else you do PopUpManager.createPopUp and keep a reference to the returned display object (the instance of the pop-up it created) and add your listeners then.  2 you make two properties in the pop up typed as function, you use them as call backs, so when you create the pop-up you set the okClickedFunction and cancelClickedFunction (or whatever your buttons may be) then in the pop-up you put cilck handlers on the buttons, check to see if the appropriate call-back function is set and call it if so, like

```
if(okClickedFunction)
    okClickedFunction();
```

Let me know if you have a specific need that makes you think you must use the AsyncToken, but from checking out the docs it looks as though it's strictly meant to work with the other RPC methods and lots of properties are read-only.

**EDIT:**

[SomeUtilClass.as]

```
private static function methodThatOpensAlert():CustomAlert
{
    return PopUpManager.createPopUp(Application.application, CustomAlert) as CustomAlert;
}
```

[CustomAlert.as]

```
[Event(type="flash.events.Event", name="button1Clicked")]
[Event(type="flash.events.Event", name="button2Clicked")]

private function button1Clicked_handler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("button1Clicked", true));
}
private function button2Clicked_handler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("button2Clicked", true));
}
```

[ThingThatUsesAlert]

```
var ca:CustomAlert = SomeUtilClass.methodThatOpensAlert();
ca.addEventListener("button1Clicked", button1ClickHandler);
ca.addEventListener("button2Clicked", button2ClickHandler);
```

And I believe mouse events bubble by default anyhow still so you could really just listen for a click event on the pop up then use the event.target to determine if it was one of the buttons your interested in.

Let me know if you can make sense of this or need more info.

Comment: Hi, Shaun. I know what you mean, but what I would like is have the method return something that returns something other components can listen to.

Comment: Also, yeah, I'm worried that AsyncToken is for RPC and so not fit for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah okay, well go with the first option and you should be good, just have the pop-up itself dispatch the events and have the method that's called to create the pop up return the instance of it.  I'll edit to give some pseudo code.